# How to scrape icons from an HTML table using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, icons

I'm trying to scrape a table on the markets.ft website which unfortunately has a number of icons in it (table: 'Lipper Leader Scorecard' - https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/ratings?s=LU0526609390:EUR).

When I use BeautifulSoup, I can grab the table but all the values are NaN.

Is there a way to scrape the icons inside the table and convert them into a numerical number?

My code is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

id_list = ['LU0526609390:EUR','IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR', 'LU1076093779:EUR', 'LU1116896363:EUR', 'LU1116896876:EUR']
urls = ['https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/ratings?s='+ x for x in id_list]

dfs =[]
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    # Some funds in the list do not have any data.
    try:
     table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
     print(table)
    except Exception:
        continue 
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), index_col=0)[0]
    dfs.append(df)

print(dfs)
```

Required Output for fund (LU0526609390):

```
                Total return  Consistent return  Preservation  Expense
Overall rating           3                3           5            5
3 year rating            3                3           5            5
5 year rating            2                3           5            5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to transform the class value to the corresponding integer

```py
import requests, bs4
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

options = {
    'mod-sprite-lipper-1': 1,
    'mod-sprite-lipper-2': 2,
    'mod-sprite-lipper-3': 3,
    'mod-sprite-lipper-4': 4,
    'mod-sprite-lipper-5': 5,
}

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
    url= 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/ratings?s=LU0526609390:EUR'
).content, 'html.parser').find('table', {'class': 'mod-ui-table'})


header = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find('thead').find_all('th')]

data = [header] + [
    [x.find('td').text.strip()] + [
        options[e.find('i') .get('class')[-1]]
        for e in x.find_all('td')[1:]
    ]
    for x in soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
]

df = pd.read_csv(
        StringIO('\n'.join([','.join(str(x) for x in xs) for xs in data])),
        index_col = 0,
        )

print(df)
```